# .onscroll function not working on single post page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a very strange bug on my site. The .onscroll function works perfectly on every page, but not on a single post.

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

// Fixed header
window.onscroll = function() {fixedHeader()};

var header = document.getElementById("header");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function fixedHeader() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}

});
```

I did different tests on other browsers, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

It also doesn't make a difference if I change this line of code:

```
window.onscroll = fixedHeader;
```

Anybody any idea?

Comment: might be you wrote some script which is conflicting scroll function in single page, debug it by removing one by one in code

Comment: Thank you for your respond charan, but it still didn't resolve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure it out. Might be a strange bug, so I re-wrote the whole code and function and now it works perfectly fine. For those of you who wants to see my new code:

ultimateartist.stickyMenu = {

```
init: function() {

    var stickyElement = $( '.stick-me' );

    if ( $( stickyElement ).length ) {

        stickyClass = 'make-sticky';

        var stickyOffset = stickyElement.scrollTop();

        // Our stand-in element for stickyElement while stickyElement is off on a scroll
        if ( ! $( '#sticky-adjuster' ).length ) {
            stickyElement.before( '<div id="sticky-adjuster"></div>' );
        }

        // Stick it on resize, scroll and load
        $( window ).on( 'resize scroll load', function(){
            var stickyOffset = $( '#sticky-adjuster' ).offset().top;
            ultimateartist.stickyMenu.stickIt( stickyElement, stickyClass, stickyOffset );
        } );

        ultimateartist.stickyMenu.stickIt( stickyElement, stickyClass, stickyOffset );

    }

},

// Stick the search form
stickIt: function ( stickyElement, stickyClass, stickyOffset ) {

    var winScroll = $( window ).scrollTop();

    if ( stickyElement.css( 'display' ) != 'none' && winScroll > stickyOffset ) {

        // If a sticky edge element exists and we've scrolled past it, hide the filter bar
        if ( ! stickyElement.hasClass( stickyClass ) ) {
            stickyElement.addClass( stickyClass );
            $( '#sticky-adjuster' ).height( stickyElement.outerHeight() ).css( 'margin-bottom', parseInt( stickyElement.css( 'marginBottom' ) ) );
        }

    // If not, remove class and sticky-adjuster properties
    } else {
        ultimateartist.stickyMenu.unstickIt();
    }

},

unstickIt: function() {
    $( '.' + stickyClass ).removeClass( stickyClass );
    $( '#sticky-adjuster' ).height( 0 ).css( 'margin-bottom', '0' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems because of id="header" is not in the single page post.so script no detect header id.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. The id is also on the single page.